# Python NumPy adding [] after operator such as where

Tags: python, numpy

I'm super new to python. I'm trying to understand some code. The code uses the NumPy library to analyze a data stream.

```
in0 = input_items[0]
mask = np.where(in0 > 0.9)[0]
(start, stop) = (mask[0], mask[-1])
blank = int(50e-6*sample_rate) # Skip first 50 us.
start = start+blank
foo = in1[start:stop] > 0.5
preamble_location = np.where(foo)[0][0]
```

In the second line np.where returns where the elements of in0 are greater than 0.9. What I don't understand is what the [0] in that line does. Similar to the last line I'm not sure what [0][0] does as well.

Comment: Could you show what's in `in0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have the following array `in0`. `np.where(in0 > 0.9)` will return you a tuple of indices.

```
in0 = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.95, 1.3, 0.5, 0.2])
```

This can be checked by printing the type

```
print (type(np.where(in0 > 0.9)))
# <class 'tuple'>
```

The length of this tuple is 1

```
print (len(np.where(in0 > 0.9)))
# 1
```

Now you need the indices of `in0` array which fulfill this condition. But `np.where` returns a tuple.

```
print (np.where(in0 > 0.9))
# (array([2, 3]),)
```

To get the list of indices, you need to use the index `[0]`

```
print (np.where(in0 > 0.9)[0])
# [2 3]
```

---

Now let's come to the second question about `[0][0]`. Consider the following example:

```
foo = in0[0:4] > 0.5
print (foo)

# array([False, False,  True,  True])
```

Now `np.where` again returns a tuple as shown above. To get the array of indices, you need to access it using index `[0]`. This will return

```
preamble_location = np.where(foo)[0]
print (preamble_location)
# [2 3]
```

Now `[0][0]` will just return the first element of this array of indices, which is the value 2. If you use `[0][1]`, you will get the second element i.e., 3.

```
preamble_location = np.where(foo)[0][0]
print (preamble_location)
# 2
```

Comment: Thanks,  that makes so much sense. My background is C and python is like speaking german to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function of Numpy : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

`[0]` is the first element of the return.

Like :

```
list = [3,2,5]
print(list[0])
```

The return will be :

```
3
```